# Find an example of a function $h(x)$ for which $h'(0)>0$ but which there is no open interval containing $0$ in which $h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Consider the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\sin\dfrac1x,&x \ne 0\\0, &x =0 \end{cases}$$

which is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and has the derivative function
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2x\sin\dfrac1x-\cos\dfrac1x,&x \ne 0\\0, &x =0 \end{cases}$$

**Question:** Show that $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Hence, find an example of a function $h(x)$ for which $h'(0)>0$ but which there is no open interval containing $0$ in which $h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

---

I have done the first part of the question.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(2x\sin\dfrac1x-\cos\dfrac1x) \ne 0$.

Since, for all $x=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$, we have $\cos\dfrac1x=1$ and $2x\sin\dfrac1x=0$

$1=1-0=|\cos\dfrac1x|-|2x\sin\dfrac1x|\le|2x\sin\dfrac1x-\cos\dfrac1x|=|2x\sin\dfrac1x-\cos\dfrac1x-0|$.

However, I could not find $h(x)$ in which $h'(0)>0$ but in which there is no open interval containing 0 such that $h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: can you consider $h(x)=ax+f(x)$ and see if there are any values of $a$ for which $h$ has required properties?

Comment: @Maesumi Got it. Thanks!